# How to check two lists with different Types but having a Common property

Tags: java, list, loops, hashmap

Assume I have two lists with different domain objects of different types: `Customer` and `Employee`.

And these objects have the common `companyId` property.

`Customer` class:

```
public static class Customer {
    private Long companyId;
    private String companyName;
}
```

`Employee` class:

```
public static class Employee {
    private Long companyId;
    private String companyName;
}
```

`Employee` has this property in common `companyId` assigned, but the `companyName` is missing.

I have two lists:

```
List<Customer> customerList;
List<Employee> employeeList;
```

What I want to do is to set the `companyName` for each `Employee` where the `companyId` from `Employee` == `companyId` of `Customer`

First I tried with two nested `for`-loops, but I think it is not very performance-vice, if I have over 1000 elements.

What is the best way with respect to performance to achieve this?

Maybe store the data from `customerList` as a `HashMap` and then for each `Employee` do `get(companyId)` or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were thinking in the right direction. Generating a `Map` which associates `companyId` of each customer with a `companyName` would be a more performant approach than using a nested `for`-loop.

When we have a `Map`, the only thing left is iterate through the list of `Employee` and if its `companyId` exists in the Map replace the `companyName` with the one that is stored in the Map.

```
public static void setCompanyNames(List<Customer> customerList,
                                   List<Employee> employeeList) {
    
    Map<Long, String> companyNameByCustomerId = customerList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Customer::getCompanyId,   // generating Keys
            Customer::getCompanyName, // generating Values
            (left, right) -> left     // resolving duplicates (this argument is need if there could be several customers with the same companyId)
        )); 
    
    for (Employee employee: employeeList) {
        Long id = employee.getCompanyId();
        if (companyNameByCustomerId.containsKey(id)) {
            employee.setCompanyName(companyNameByCustomerId.get(id));
        }
    }
}
```